# New Button is not visible in websphere portal server 8.5. Give error: You do not have access to configure any libraries

Tags: websphere-liberty, websphere-8, websphere-portal

I have already check all the accessibility at library level as well as resource level. But new button is not visible.

[Please click this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8Utp.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8Utp.jpg)

Comment: Please provide more details/code on the context you work with.

Comment: what libraries can you see from within the shared settings if you go under preferences?  have you added any to the view?  try that first,  then see if you can at least browse them, if you cannot please show us the library in the web content page in admin, and the permissions on the library in question

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8Utp.jpg

Comment: that is just the same image again, and not very helpful, click under the preferences on the left hand side and go into edit shared settings and see if you can see any libraries there, if not go to the wrench icon, go to web content, click on libraries, and show us what libraries are there, and pic one and look and see what access your user has

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have not installed the complete package. Please try installing the WCM component and hopefully it should work.

Comment: I do not find the complete package in IBM support.Can you provide the complete package of the WCM component.Please give me the war file.